# how + adjective + a/an + noun:

Tags: sentence-structure

As far as I know I can ***use this structure(how + adjective + a/an + noun)  with singular countable nouns***. (The plural form is not possible, nor is using the definite article “the.” )

> 1- No matter ***how bad a mood*** you were in, you shouldn't have
>   gone there. (okay)
>
> 2- ***How soft a pillow*** do you need? (okay)
>
> 3- ***How long the story*** is it going to be? (wrong)

But I have seen these following sentences on a journal website and now I am really confused. (I have just learnt the rule I wrote above. Before not knowing it these following sentences would be okay to me but now I don't get it.

> 4- I can't describe ***how bad the situation*** was all night. (I don't know why this one is okay according to the rule)
>
> 5- Waiting to hear just ***how bad the news*** is. (I don't know why this one is okay according to the rule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule you have learned (how+adj+a/an+noun) with the restriction on "the" only applies to direct questions. With reported speech, indirect questions, and direct statements you can use "a/an" or "the."

The following examples all work:

> Direct Question:
>
> - **How long a story** is it?
>
> Indirect Speech:
>
> - She asked **how long a story** it is.
> - She asked **how long the story** is.
> - I told you **how long a story** it is.
> - I told you **how long the story** is.
>
> Direct Statement:
>
> - **How long a story** is depends on factors like the complexity of the plot and the amount of dialogue.
> - **How long the story** is depends on a variety of factors.

In statements and reported speech, using "the" is perfectly fine with both countable and uncountable nouns. The following examples are both fine:

> No matter **how nice the weather** looks, you should always carry an umbrella. (uncountable)
>
> I know **how ugly the dress** is, but you should still compliment the bride. (countable)

Answer (score 2):

Question (3):

> 3- How long the story is it going to be?

is indeed wrong. It should be:

> 3'- **How long is the story** going to be?

Sentences (4) and (5) are correct because they are the reported versions of these direct questions, where "how bad" is separated from "the situation" (just as "how long" is separated from "the story" in (3')):

4'- **How bad was the situation** all night?

5'- **How bad is the news**?

When the questions are reported, the subject with a definite article happens to appear next to "how + adjective," but they are two different structures: subject complement *how* adjective + subject *the* noun

Comment: *"How long **a** story is it going to be?"* is correct, though.  Either way I don't feel your answer addresses the question, which is whether it is OK to use the direct article with this structure, as in the provided examples.

Comment: OP wanted to confirm if using the definite (not direct) article was possible in direct questions with "how + adjective". It is not. "how + adjective" can only be followed by "the" in embedded questions where "the" forms part of the subject.

Comment: @Andrew Has understood my question better.

Comment: Let him provide a better answer if he can then. You're welcome @TalhaÖzden

Comment: @Gustavson I am sorry if I offended you. I am trying to figure out how "that/how+adjective+a/an+noun" form works. I have one more question that could provide better understanding to my first question. Is it possible to use this sentence: "They weren't that nice people after all."

Comment: You should say: "They weren't such nice people after all."